# Very large pandas dataframe - keeping count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Assume this is a sample of my data: [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMoU4.jpg)

the entire dataframe is stored in a csv file (dataframe.csv) that is 40GBs so I can't open all of it at once.
I am hoping to find the most dominant 25 names for all genders. My instinct is to create a for loop that runs through the file (because I can't open it at once), and have a python dictionary that holds the counter for each name (that I will increment as I go through the data).
To be honest, I'm confused on where to even start with this (how to create the dictionary, since to_dict() does not appear to do what I'm looking for). And also, if this is even a good solution? Is there a more efficient way someone can think of?

SUMMARY -- sorry if the question is a bit long:
the csv file storing the data is very big and I can't open it at once, but I'd like to find the top 25 dominant names in the data. Any ideas on what to do and how to do it?
I'd appreciate any help I can get! :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Two notes: 1. Please don't add pictures of anything. Instead, share reproducible code to regenerate your data set. 2. Please share your effort with your code progress, regardless of how potentially bad it may be - no worries.

Comment: I'm so sorry. This is a sample I found online as the data I'm working with is confidential which means unfortunately I cant share the data. So far my code has been organizing things until I get here. I don't really have any code for this problem. I only have an idea on what to do and I was hoping for some input or help in the matter. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your interesting task! I've implemented pure `numpy` + `pandas` solution. It uses sorted array to keep names and counts. Hence algorithm should be around `O(n * log n)` complexity.

I didn't any hash table in numpy, hash table definitely would be faster (`O(n)`). Hence I used existing sorting/inserting routines of numpy.

Also I used `.read_csv()` from `pandas` with `iterator = True, chunksize = 1 << 24` params, this allows reading file in chunks and producing pandas dataframes of fixed size from each chunk.

Note! In the first runs (until program is debugged) set `limit_chunks` (number of chunks to process) in code to small value (like `5`). This is to check that whole program runs correctly on partial data.

Program needs to run one time command `python -m pip install pandas numpy` to install these 2 packages if you don't have them.

Progress is printed once in a while, total megabytes done plus speed.

Result will be printed to console plus saved to `res_fname` file name, all constants configuring script are placed in the beginning of script. `topk` constant controls how many top names will be outputed to file/console.

Interesting how fast is my solution. If it is to slow maybe I devote some time to write nice `HashTable` class using pure `numpy`.

You can also try and run next code [here online](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow63986055#main.py).

```
import os, math, time, sys
# Needs: python -m pip install pandas numpy
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import pandas, numpy

fname = 'test.csv'
fname_res = 'test.res'
chunk_size = 1 << 24
limit_chunks = None # Number of chunks to process, set to None if to process whole file
all_genders = ['Male', 'Female']
topk = 1000 # How many top names to output
progress_step = 1 << 23 # in bytes

fsize = os.path.getsize(fname)
#el_man = enlighten.get_manager() as el_man
#el_ctr = el_man.counter(color = 'green', total = math.ceil(fsize / 2 ** 20), unit = 'MiB', leave = False)

tables = {g : {
    'vals': np.full([1], chr(0x10FFFF), dtype = np.str_),
    'cnts': np.zeros([1], dtype = np.int64),
} for g in all_genders}

tb = time.time()

def Progress(
    done, total = min([fsize] + ([chunk_size * limit_chunks] if limit_chunks is not None else [])),
    cfg = {'progressed': 0, 'done': False},
):
    if not cfg['done'] and (done - cfg['progressed'] >= progress_step or done >= total):
        if done < total:
            while cfg['progressed'] + progress_step <= done:
                cfg['progressed'] += progress_step
        else:
            cfg['progressed'] = total
        sys.stdout.write(
            f'{str(round(cfg["progressed"] / 2 ** 20)).rjust(5)} MiB of ' +
            f'{str(round(total / 2 ** 20)).rjust(5)} MiB ' +
            f'speed {round(cfg["progressed"] / 2 ** 20 / (time.time() - tb), 4)} MiB/sec\n'
        )
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if done >= total:
            cfg['done'] = True

with open(fname, 'rb', buffering = 1 << 26) as f:
    for i, df in enumerate(pd.read_csv(f, iterator = True, chunksize = chunk_size)):
        if limit_chunks is not None and i >= limit_chunks:
            break
        if i == 0:
            name_col = df.columns.get_loc('First Name')
            gender_col = df.columns.get_loc('Gender')
        names = np.array(df.iloc[:, name_col]).astype('str')
        genders = np.array(df.iloc[:, gender_col]).astype('str')
        for g in all_genders:
            ctab = tables[g]
            gnames = names[genders == g]
            vals, cnts = np.unique(gnames, return_counts = True)
            if vals.size == 0:
                continue
            if ctab['vals'].dtype.itemsize < names.dtype.itemsize:
                ctab['vals'] = ctab['vals'].astype(names.dtype)
            poss = np.searchsorted(ctab['vals'], vals)
            exist = ctab['vals'][poss] == vals
            ctab['cnts'][poss[exist]] += cnts[exist]
            nexist = np.flatnonzero(exist == False)
            ctab['vals'] = np.insert(ctab['vals'], poss[nexist], vals[nexist])
            ctab['cnts'] = np.insert(ctab['cnts'], poss[nexist], cnts[nexist])
        Progress(f.tell())
    Progress(fsize)
    
with open(fname_res, 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    for g in all_genders:
        f.write(f'{g}:\n\n')
        print(g, '\n')
        order = np.flip(np.argsort(tables[g]['cnts']))[:topk]
        snames, scnts = tables[g]['vals'][order], tables[g]['cnts'][order]
        if snames.size > 0:
            for n, c in zip(np.nditer(snames), np.nditer(scnts)):
                n, c = str(n), int(c)
                if c == 0:
                    continue
                f.write(f'{c} {n}\n')
                print(c, n.encode('ascii', 'replace').decode('ascii'))
        f.write(f'\n')
        print()
```

Comment: I forgot to take `NaN`s in the table/csv. To do that I need to know how they are stored inside CSV, what string represents them, etc. Also I expect to be only two genders Male, Female. You may put other genders (including NaN string for gender) into config of genders in the beginning of script. If NaNs are represented by "NaN" string in CSV, everything will work fine, just add "NaN" gender. And there will be "NaN" names in output result also.

Comment: Thank you for the help! If I want to get a summary of all the salaries by a different names (How much money do all the Lindas make? etc.) to see who is the top paid names, how would I do that? I would want it to be a bit automated so I can find the top paid names rather than to find how much each name makes individually

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("sample_data.csv")
print(df['First Name'].value_counts())
```

The second line will convert your csv into a pandas dataframe and the third line should print the occurances of each name.
https://dfrieds.com/data-analysis/value-counts-python-pandas.html

Comment: Thank you for this simple approach! If I want to get a summary of all the salaries by a different names (How much money do all the Lindas make? etc.) to see who is the top paid names, how would I do that? I would want it to be a bit automated so I can find the top paid names rather than to find how much each name makes individually.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be a case where pandas is really going to be an advantage. But if you're committed to going down that route, change the read_csv [chunksize paramater](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), then filter out the useless columns.

Perhaps consider using a different set of tooling such as a database or even vanilla python using a generator to populate a dict in the form of name:count.